# How to kill a thread in delphi?

Tags: delphi

In delphi, a method in TThread is terminate. It seems a subthread can not kill another thread by calling terminate or free.
For example
A(main form), B (a thread unit), C (another form).

B is sending data to main form and C (by calling syncronize), we tried to terminate B within C while B is executing by calling B.terminate. But this method does not work and B is still working until it ends in execute method.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to check for Terminate in the thread for this to work. For instance:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    //Here you do a chunk of your work.
    //It's important to have chunks small enough so that "while not Terminated"
    //gets checked often enough.
  end;
  //Here you finalize everything before thread terminates
end;
```

With this, you can call

```
MyThread.Terminate;
```

And it'll terminate as soon as it finishes processing another chunk of work. This is called "graceful thread termination" because the thread itself is given a chance to finish any work and prepare for termination.

There is another method, called 'forced termination'. You can call:

```
TerminateThread(MyThread.Handle);
```

When you do this, Windows forcefully stops any activity in the thread. This does not require checking for "Terminated" in the thread, but potentially can be extremely dangerous, because you're killing thread in the middle of operation. Your application might crash after that.

That's why you never use TerminateThread until you're absolutely sure you have all the possible consequences figured out. Currently you don't, so use the first method.

Comment: It's not only the application may crash, but also resources used by the thead won't be deallocated. TerminateThread() is an "extrema ratio" call.

Comment: @himself: you could have the thread call "Abort" inside the thread context when it finds Terminated set to True. "Abort" will raise a silent exception. Sometimes this way you get easier logic than having a big "while not Terminated" loop.

Comment: Dear himself: Just test your code but the thread can not gracefully exit. While not terminated do begin UNTIL the thread Execute function ends. Why? Instead, Terminatethread function does good job though it is not recommended by most experts.

Comment: @user482742: Edit your question and add the code so we can tell you what's the problem.

Comment: @himself what unit should I write into the uses list to make TerminateThread work? If that's "Windows" then it needs 2 parameters...

Comment: Not very useful if your thread is stuck in some external windows function.

Answer (score 17):

Actually,

currently most voted answer to this question is incorrect (so as 34 upvoters...) in regard how to forcefully kill a thread.

You **do not** use `ThreadId` as a parameter to `TerminateThread` procedure. Using `ThreadId` will cause most likely an "Invalid handle" error or in worse case scenerio - will kill a different thread.

You should pass a [thread handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a parameter:

```
TerminateThread(MyThread.Handle);
```

More about differences between thread's handle and id can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101918/thread-id-vs-thread-handle).

**Edit**

Seems @himself corrected his mistake after seeing my answer, so this is no longer relevant.

Comment: @kobik yes and I did so in the past, but look how this community works: a lot of people gave +1 without actually checking if himself's answer is correct.

Answer (score 13):

Terminate does not kill a thread; it sets the `Terminated` property to inform the thread that it needs to terminate.  It's the thread's responsibility to watch for `Terminated` and shut itself down gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

All the `Terminate` method does is it sets the `Terminated` property to true. So you have to manually keep checking that property and then exit the thread method when it is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you might want to terminate a thread then you could be better off spawning another app and killing that if you think its failed - windows will then tidy up after you.