# How do I stop a thread before it's finished running?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a thread called TMyThread and I overrode the Execute procedure like this:

```
 procedure TMyThread.Execute;
 Begin
     repeat
     //Some Work 
     Sleep(5000);
     //Some Work 2;
     Sleep(5000); 
     until FActive=False
 End;
```

In the main form I have button called 'Destroy My Thread'. I want to destroy my thread but the problem is that my thread will be destroyed only if it finish its work. I want to destroy my thread even it has not finished its work. How do I do this?

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044855/how-to-kill-a-thread-in-delphi

Comment: Technically that's possible, but it's a *really* bad idea. Don't kill threads, tell them to commit suicide. The correct solution is having your thread check a flag(such as the `Terminated` property) often enough.

Comment: And if you want your worker thread to sleep, don't use sleep, because the thread is not listening (to Terminated) during that time. Use Events and WaitForSingleObject as e.g. specified here: http://objectmix.com/delphi/402360-tthread-sleep-terminate.html (found when Googling "delphi terminate thread setevent")

Comment: @Jan Doggen : Yes that's it .. using TEvent solve my problem .. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TEvent can solve this problem 
this is an eg :

```
  uses SyncObjs;
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
       private
         FTerminateEvent: TEvent;
       protected
         procedure Execute; override  ;
       public
        constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean); overload;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Stop;
       end;
    constructor TMyThread.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
    begin
    FTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, 'FTerminateEvent');
    inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
    end;

    destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
    begin
     FTerminateEvent.Free;
     inherited;
    end;

    procedure TMyThread.Stop;
    begin
    Terminate;
    FTerminateEvent.SetEvent;
    end;

    procedure TMyThread.Execute;
    begin
      while not Terminated do
      begin
      // do somthing interesting!
       FTerminateEvent.WaitFor(5000);
      end;
    end;
```

Now if i want to kill my thread ,all what i have to do is calling MyThread.Stop than calling MyThread.Free .

Comment: Why did you select to implement your own parallel mechanism rather than using Terminate

Comment: To be clear on how to do this, you need to override `TThread.TerminatedSet` and there call `FTerminateEvent.SetEvent`. And make sure that you free `FTerminateEvent` after you have called `inherited Destroy`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 23):

Your thread's `Execute` method must regularly check the state of the thread's `Terminated` property. And if it is `True`, then the thread `Execute` method must exit.

So, a typical `Execute` method might look like this:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    DoNextPieceOfWork
end;
```

It looks like your thread has its own `FActive` flag that is performing the same task. The problem with that is that `TThread` doesn't know about it. So you should get rid of `FActive` and instead use the built in mechanism.

When you call `Free` on the thread it will call `Terminate`. That sets `Terminated` to be `True`. Then it waits for the thread method to exit. That will happen because your thread notices that `Terminated` is `True` and quits. And then the thread's destructor can continue and finish the job of tidying up the thread.

---

Looking at the code in your answer, it would be better written to make use of the existing `Terminate` mechanism.

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTerminateEvent: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
  FTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  FTerminateEvent.Free;
end;

procedure TMyThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FTerminateEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    // do somthing interesting!
    FTerminateEvent.WaitFor(5000);
  end;
end;
```

Now there's no need for a separate `Stop` method. You can just call `Free` on the thread. Then `Terminate` is called. And then `TerminatedSet` is called. Then the event is signaled. Then `Execute` terminates. And then the thread can go away.

---

Having said that, I'm struggling to think of a scenario where a 5000ms timeout would be the best approach. I don't know why you are doing this, but I'd guess that you are trying to throttle the thread so that it doesn't run *hot*. You want to avoid a busy loop. That's admirable, but using a fixed timeout is not the way to do it. The way to do it is to wait on a synchronisation event, typically an event. Then when there is more work to be done, the event becomes signaled and your thread wakes up.

Comment: i use FActive instead of Terminated

Comment: David , I dont wana my thread to waits for the thread method (The work) to exit..

Answer (score 1):

You really are approaching this problem completely wrong. Code your threads to only do work that you want them to do, and then there will be no need to "reach in from the outside" to control them. You feel the need to control this thread from the outside because it's doing something you don't want it to do -- well then why did you code it to do that in the first place?

Comment: since i need to use Sleep Method as a time waiting before i do my work

Comment: You need interruptible sleep

Comment: @user1720557: That's fine, then sleep. But when you wake up, make an intelligent decision about what to do next.