# Delphi - terminate thread after single successful execution or by user cancellation

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe3

New here. Relatively new to Delphi as well so plz be kind...

My actual (domain) problem: small VCL app that communicates with two laboratory balances via serial, balances output weight readings on a continuous 1-second interval, said weighs are displayed in the captions of two labels. When user clicks a 'Weigh' button, I need to wait for a valid weight (stable, within range, etc.) and record said weight once, -or-, allow the user to cancel the weighing.

My problem as implemented. Creating a separate thread when user clicks weigh button using TEvent template from S.MAHDI / David Heffernan as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033894/how-do-i-stop-a-thread-before-its-finished-running).

```
TWeigh = class(TThread)
  private
    FTerminateEvent: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TWeigh.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  FTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  inherited;
end;

destructor TWeigh.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  FTerminateEvent.Free;
end;

procedure TWeigh.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FTerminateEvent.SetEvent;
  Beep;
end;

procedure TWeigh.Execute();
begin
  while (not Terminated) do begin
    if (validweight) then begin
      Synchronize(procedure begin
        DoStuff();
      end);
    end;
    FTerminateEvent.WaitFor(100);
  end;
end;
```

My form button click event looks like:

```
{ Weigh is global implementation var of class TWeigh }
procedure TForm1.btnWeighClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  B : TButton;
begin
  B := Sender as TButton;
  if (B.Caption = 'Weigh') then Weigh := TWeigh.Create(False);
  if (B.Caption = 'Cancel') then Weigh.Free;
  B.Caption := Trim(Copy('CancelWeigh ',AnsiPos(B.Caption,'Weigh Cancel'),6));
end;
```

This appears to work fine for the cancellation requirement. It's my understanding that Synchronize messages the main thread and it is the main thread that executes the anonymous procedure containing DoStuff(), so there should be no race conditions between the user clicking cancel and a valid weight coming in. (Right?)

I'm stuck on how to have the weigh thread only execute a single time. Various solutions I've tried have resulted in deadlocks (add Weigh.Free to DoStuff()... didn't take long to figure out why THAT doesn't work), single execution but non-free'd threads (self.Terminate after the synchronize section within the if block), or various other nonsense.

So, is it even possible to have this thread free and/or kill itself while still allowing for the parent thread via user input to kill it, or do I need a completely different architecture for this?

Edit in response to why a loop: I only need a single reading, but the time until I get that single reading varies between immediately and never.  The balances can take several seconds to stabilize, during which time unstable readings are read and displayed every second. The ability for the user to cancel is still required because the reading might never be valid (under-overweight).

Comment: If you only want to execute once, why do you have a loop?

Comment: Also, don't test the text of buttons to learn which button it is. Use `if button=thisButton then`.

Comment: Hi David, nice to finally 'meet' the person who's probably taught me more than anyone else so far. =) I've edited my answer to explain why a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to quit the thread when you've finished calling `DoStuff`. That can be done like so:

```
procedure TWeigh.Execute();
begin
  while (not Terminated) do begin
    if (validweight) then begin
      Synchronize(procedure begin
        DoStuff();
      end);
      exit;
    end;
    FTerminateEvent.WaitFor(100);
  end;
end;
```

I have to say that this looks more appropriate for a timer than a thread. All the work is done on the main thread, and the thread just appears to be there to check a flag at a regular interval. That sounds like a timer. In fact, why even a timer? Why not fire the `DoStuff` when you set the flag true?

Comment: The exit call does work, thread goes away. However... `Destroy` is not called (because `FreeOnTerminate` is false?), so is this a memory leak? What about the `FTerminateEvent`, does that die with the thread? A timer might be a better solution. I may need to `DoStuff` off the main thread but it might turn out to be a YAGNI. In meantime thank you, I'll mark this as good and figure out how to use the memory manager now that I have a actual problem to use it on.

Comment: Either FreeOnTerminate, or hold a reference to the thread which you can Free

Comment: @KevinMetzger: To expand on David's response, if you call `Free` on a `TThread` object, it will free it immediately if the thread is finished, or wait until the thread terminates and then free it if the thread is not finished.

Comment: Thanks Mason, that actually helped quite a bit. I was conflating the executing/termination of a thread with the instantiation/freeing of the memory used to hold it. So the exit just ends the Execute (which is why the thread goes away in prcessexplorer) but TWeigh is still allocated and can be Free'd from the main thread at any time. This gives me much more confidence that I can avoid memory leaks.